# Prove that there exists an element of V which cannot be expressed as a linear combination of elements of X.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors

I am really confused about this question and have no idea what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

Let V = P(R) be the vector space of polynomials with coefficients in R and let X be a finite subset of V . Prove that there exists an element of V which cannot be expressed as a linear combination of elements of X.

Comment: How many finite subsets of V have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since $X$ is finite, there is $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n>\deg(x),\,\forall x\in X$.
And note that $\deg(x+y)\leq\max\left\{\deg(x),\deg(y)\right\}$.